# R - Shiny App : How to host a Shiny App without interruption? If possible on Github or Shiny Server

Tags: r, github, shiny, shiny-server

So my shiny app goes to sleep since it is running locally on my computer, I want people to be able to access it even when my computer is turned off, i.e **I want it to be hosted somewhere online** so that it can continuously run. Any help would be great

[image: SS of Shiny App Management]

Comment: That image looks like an app hosted on shinyapps.io, not locally? In any case, these are your options: https://shiny.rstudio.com/deploy/

Comment: Thanks @neilfws. Just so I understand, If it is hosted on shinyapps.io, does that mean that it can be accessed at any point by someone with the url, even it is isn't running locally on my computer? 
Thanks, this is a pretty noob question.

Comment: Yes, the app is accessible to anyone with the URL. It will awake from the sleeping state when accessed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it all figured out!